# create scroll bar like lion mac os x in wpf auto hide when no scrolling

Tags: macos, scroll, osx-lion

how create lion scroll with wpf
when no scrolling hide

```
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard >
                                        <Storyboard >
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="0.7" To="0.2" Duration="0:0:0.3" BeginTime="0:0:5" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </MultiTrigger>
```